# How do I select random rows without using df.sample()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random

If I wanted to select rows randomly from a data frame without using df.sample(), would something like

```
import random
peopleCount = people.iloc[[random.randint(1, 101)]], :]
```

work? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes your way should work. Is there a reason you don't want to use `.sample()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could select N rows by using take and permutaions:

```
peopleCount = people.take(np.random.permutation(len(people))[:N])
```

by `df.sample()` would be my primary choice.